# How to show that $\forall k\in(0,1), \exists L>0, \frac{1+kt}{1-kt} \leq e^{Lt}$ on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show the following statement,

> $$\forall k\in(0,1), \exists L>0, \forall t\in[0, 1], \frac{1+kt}{1-kt} \leq e^{Lt}$$

This may be a very simple question but I can't see the trick.

I tried differentiating but it led nowhere, or maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: What happens if $t=\frac 1 k$?

Comment: If $k<1$ you get an easy proof using the fact that $\frac  1 {1-kt}\le \frac 1  {1-k}$. You can take $L=\frac {2k}{1-k}$.

Comment: Sorry I am almost afraid to ask because it seems that I am missing something that should be obvious, I still don't see it...

Comment: This is not true for $k\ge1$ since $\frac{1+kt}{1-kt}\to\infty$ at $t=\frac1k$.

Comment: Modified the question accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $k \in (0, 1)$, let $g(t) = \ln \left(\frac{1 + kt}{1 - kt}\right)$, then $$g'(t) = \frac{k}{1+kt} + \frac{k}{1-kt} = \frac{2k}{1-k^2t^2} \le \frac{2}{1-k^2} = L$$ you can then write for all $t\in [0, 1]$,

\begin{align}
g(t) = \int_0^t g'(u)\mathrm d u \le Lt.
\end{align}

Take the exponnetial and you have what you are looking for.